# Keeping the same key and iv for encrypting post content

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt and decrypt some wordpress posts. Only the content field i care about.

Is it safe to use the same key and iv for the process?

Comment: You really don't give us much information. Safe from what and from whom?

Comment: Might want to check answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324149/how-to-securely-handle-aes-key-and-iv-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  To which degree it is unsafe, depends on many factors.  The reason that you choose to use an algorithm that provides you with the facility to use both an IV and a key should be a clue that they should not, in fact, be the same.   The entire purpose of an IV is, in fact, to allow you to safely reuse a single key, by changing the IV.

However, another nice property of an IV is that it need not be a secret.  Only the key must remain secret.  This is why IVs are often sent in the clear along with a ciphertext.  So, depending on the constraints of your system, hopefully you can find a way to use a unique IV which will help you to maintain the expected security properties of the algorithm and mode you choose.